# DTCoreText got a warning of " UI API called on a background thread"

Tags: ios, dtcoretext

seems the latest code of DTCoreText in the Github still didn't fix this . how to fix this warning well?
[image]

and the stacktrace is as this

```
PID: 80642, TID: 3065451, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   iKM                                 0x00000001031a2232 -[DTAttributedTextContentView drawLayer:inContext:] + 210
5   QuartzCore                          0x000000010766502c -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 267
6   QuartzCore                          0x00000001075b1042 _ZL18tiled_layer_renderP16_CAImageProviderjjjjPv + 1817
7   QuartzCore                          0x000000010763b4ce _ZL21CAImageProviderThreadPjb + 789
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cc8443c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cc89352 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1458
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cc901f9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 772
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cc8fe97 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010d14c1ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010d14bc4d start_wqthread + 13
```

Comment: What's the stacktrace? What method triggers the `drawLayer:inContext:` in a background thread?

Comment: @Larme i have post the stacktrace , and  it seems can't help alot

Comment: Is this happening inside `CATiledLayer` (or the hierarchy of one)?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist it's happed in DTAttributedTextContentView

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist yes ,it's using DTTiledLayerWithoutFade,subclass of CATiledLayer

Answer (score 0):

the new version of dtcoretext fix this by adding main thread drawing only in layer